# React is not displaying local image loaded from Json

Tags: reactjs

Currently looking to load an image from a .json file into a another Json by using its path and linking a string of the path to the image Here is the Data Json. Currently the webpage "using npm start on local host" it desplays the border of the image but not the image itself. Ive tried editing the path for idk how long and the rest of the text appears as well. Also note all images are currently in a folder called "Images" in public

```
export const CryptoChain = [{
    "id":0,
    "name":'TestEthereum',
    "coinContract":'MainNetETH',
    "swapContract":'0xf9ab07031cde0fe82B13e2e3C1463760ad5774C5',
    "coinImage":'/Images/eth.jpg',
    "exchangeImage":'/uniswap.png'
}, {
    "id":1,
    "name":'TestUni',
    "coinContract":'MainNetETH',
    "swapContract":'0xf9ab07031cde0fe82B13e2e3C1463760ad5774C5',
    "coinImage":'/Images/eth.jpg',
    "exchangeImage":'/uniswap.png'
}]
```

and the code for the file im calling it in

```
// JavaScript source code
import React from 'react';
import {CryptoChain} from './CryptoChain';

export default function Trans1(props){
    
    
    return(
        <div className="Trans1">
        <div> hello </div>
        <div> {props.name}</div>
        
        <img scr = {props.coinImage} width={250} height={250} alt =""/>
         
        
        </div>
        
        
            
    );
}
```

Heres the rendering file Note im just using react with the create-react-app

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';
import Trans1 from'./Tran-1';
import {CryptoChain} from './CryptoChain'



const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  
    <figure>
   <Trans1 name={CryptoChain[0].name} coinImage={CryptoChain[0].coinImage}/>
   </figure>
  
);
//<Trans1 name={CryptoChain[0].name} coinImage={CryptoChain[0].coinImage}/>
// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
```

Ive tried fiddling with require using it like so

```
<img scr = {require({props.coinImage}).default} width={250} height={250} alt =""/>
```

but i keep getting a syntax error.

i also tried to load the image from the json directly rather than a path but that didnt work either.

Comment: For starters it's `<img src=` not `<img scr=`.

Comment: I blame that on debugging and posting the current syntax error is `SyntaxError: E:\projects\Coding Stuff\LastChance\crypto-atm\src\Tran-1.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (13:34)

  11 |         <div> {props.name}</div>
  12 |
> 13 |         <img src = {require({props.coinImage}.default)} width={250} height={250} alt =""/>
     |                                   ^`